# Error on G360 Execute 360 when importing TIF file format

Tags: vb6, image-processing, g360, execute360

I am using the CAL and eiStream Imaging software to create a workitem (document) with a TIF import file.

The workitem gets created without a problem, but as soon as I add the import file I receive an error saying incorrect format.

This only occurs on some TIF images.

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute 360 TIF documents falls under a seperate category than normal CLASS and Import files.

You are only able to store TIF documents in Group4 Black and White TIF format.

You are going to have to convert all your TIF images to Group4 before importing to Execute 360 workflow.